# Использование subprocess python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна помощь с одним вопросом. Есть команда

```
Rezult = sub.run(['psexec','\\\\192.168.0.1','hostname'] shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE)
```

она отрабатывает нормально результат выводиться.

А вот если изменить команду на

```
sub.run(['psexec','\\\\192.168.0.1','ipconfig', '/all'] shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE)
```

команда отрабатывает без ошибок но сам результат выполнения команды не выводиться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: не может первая команда нормально выводить результат, потому что в ней синтаксическая ошибка. То же самое со второй. Они обе выводят ошибку, а не результат.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import subprocess as sub
sys_response = sub.run(['psexec','\\\\192.168.0.1','ipconfig', '/all'], shell=True, capture_output=True)
print(sys_response.stdout, sys_response.stderr)
```

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо что обратили внимания на мой вопрос, на данный момент такой код и есть как представлен у вас, но вот по чему то результат команды не выводиться.

Comment: @Tenobran, А если в консоли запустить что выводит?

Comment: Вот сейчас посмотрел в консоли пишет что команда неопознанная или неполная, я так думаю что /all как то он не правильно его воспринимает.

Comment: @Tenobran, к сожалению с использованием конкретно этой команды врятли чем-то помогу, не установлен пакет `psexec`, не могу протестировать.

Comment: Ещё раз проверил, в консоли нормально все получилось код корректно отрабатывает а вот в оболочки PyCharm выдает ошибку..

Answer (score 0):

Может все таки воспользоваться `system`?

```py
from os import system
from os import path
from os import remove

system("psexec \\192.168.0.1 hostname > out.txt")
if path.exists("out.txt):
  with open("out.txt") as f:
    includes = f.read()
  print(includes)
  remove("out.txt")
```

Вывод направляется в файл, файл читается, затем выводится и удаляется. Ну, и вывод можно сделать не через `print`, а воспользоваться `sys.stdout`